# How to create a user with AbstractBaseUser or AbstractUser. (Login Error)

Tags: python, django, web, authentication, abstract-class

I am trying to use my Person class as user in models.py. However I tried using AbstractUser and AbstractBaseUser. Both of them give me errors in the part where I try to log in, I tried several ways until I realized that I need help from someone with more experience and knowledge than I do.

My models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models

class Pessoa(AbstractUser):
    id_pessoa = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cnpj = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    senha = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False)
    ativo = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    datacadastro = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    cidade = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    uf = models.CharField(max_length=2, blank=True, null=True)
    USERNAME_FIELD = 'cnpj'

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'pessoa'
```

Detail: I am unable to remove or add fields in any template I am using, because I have used `inespectdb` to create the models based on the database i am using (*the same one that is already full of data*). Any change, **with the exception of basic changes**, is out of the cogitation.

Below my **`views.py`** with def that validates the login and redirects to the *dashboard*.

```
def dash_login(request):
    form = LoginForm(request.POST, None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #if form.is_valid():
        username = form.data['cnpj']
        password = form.data['senha']
        user = authenticate(username=username)
        print(username)
        #p = Pessoa.objects.filter(cnpj=form.data['cnpj']).values('id_pessoa')[0]['id_pessoa']
        #login(request, user)
        print(request.user.is_authenticated)
        #return render(request, 'dashboard.html')
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})
```

I use `print()` to test the commands before running out, at the moment when it arrives on the line:

```
user = authenticate(username=username)
```

**It triggers this error:**

> File"C:\Users\Pichau\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py",
>   line 85, in _execute return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
>   django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column pessoa.password does not
>   exist LINE 1: SELECT "pessoa"."password", "pessoa"."last_login",
>   "pessoa"....
>
> ** Regardless I put password inside the authenticate error is
>   shot. **

**This was the second option:**

Where I fall into the same error, if I remove the `p` and use `return render (request, 'dashboard.html')` I'm redirecting without the user id, which causes me problems getting its data inside the dashboard.

However I still have the main problem, this table is logging in to Django login and not in the login I created within `models.py | forms.py`

Anyway, appreciate the help for anything in this post, will be grateful for anyone who give me any direction.

Comment: did you ran `./manage.py makemigrations` and `./manage.py migrate`?

Comment: @ruddra OP is specifically not letting Django manage those models.

Comment: But @Nicolas where do you want the password to be stored? You haven't got a password field on that model.

Comment: @ruddra Yes, doesn't have more migrations for do, and i don't know what its missing here.

Comment: @DanielRoseman the field for password it's ''senha'', but how i specifiy for django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no ability to set an option for the password field the way you can with USERNAME_FIELD. However, one thing to bear in mind is that the name of the Django model field doesn't have to match what's in the underlying db table; you can use the [`db_column`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#db-column) option on your field definition:

```
password = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, db_column='senha')
```

The other issue is that you should certainly be using AbstractBaseUser, not AbstractUser; the latter adds a load of fields that you don't want or have.

Comment: Thanks for the help Daniel.
I will test this, but when i try use AbstractBaseUser, i take some errors or i do some things not correctly, thats why i got surrender use it. Can you give me some basic example for try here? Or more help about AbstractBaseUser?! 
I tried some resources but i am little bit lost with them.

Comment: Okay, so, i think i solved that problem, but now i am getting trouble in use the model, like get data from any Field, now its showing *maximum recursion depth exceeded* when i try use Pessoa.object etc.
I guess it's the same problem, because i take away the line that i use the model for get data. But i dont know if the problem it's AbstractBaseModel, or something different